# Simple Ajax Request to Laravel Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel-4

Trying simple return and display of user info using ajax with laravel backend. Using latest JQuery and Laravel and MySQL. Here's the simple route:

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    $users = User::all();
    return $users;
});
```

This works fine when calling by url in browser.

Here's the simple ajax request:

```
$().ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/users",
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "JsonpCallback"
  })
  .done(function( data ) 
  {
    JsonpCallback( data );
  })
  .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) 
  {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus + "   /   " + errorThrown );
  });
  function JsonpCallback( json )
  {
    $( '#mainContent' ).html( json.result );
  }
  return false;
});
```

The user records are being returned in to the dom and I can see them via dev tools network response, but the .fail kicks every time and the callback is never called. The fail is:

```
Request failed: parsererror / Error: JasonpCallback was never called.
```

I have tried every solution I can find for a few days now and could really use help. It has to be something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: Did you try the url without http? just call /users. The parseerror indicates, that maybe the datatype is wrong

Comment: Maybe it's stupid, but have you tried to move the `function JsonpCallback` outside every other function?

Comment: pc-shooter - Ultimately the html/javascript will be an app on a device and will need the full path to the server. I did try just now, but .fail still fires with blank info.

Dheed - It pretty much is outside the other functions, as I read it, but I move it even outside the ready with same results. It's not that the callback isn't working, it's that .done is not firing and .fail is so callback is never being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is expecting a `jsonp` response, but `return $users` is returning plain `json`. Either switch `dataType` to `json`, or instead:

```php
return Response::json($users)->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));
```

...from your route.

See the Laravel docs under [creating a JSONP response](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses).

Comment: Thanks damiani. Your solution does allow callback to fire. I’ve gone a diff route, but know I will need that at some point. I had tried json datatype but browser bawked at cors. Main focus is cross-platform Native App using Cordova. Turns out Cordova allows cors. So added cors access in index.php in laravel for testing in browser and can use laravel views eliminating need to decode jsonp and reformat on device, if that makes sense.